# Is $f= \sum c_n \phi_n(x)$ in baby Rudin 8.11?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-series

> The natural question which now arises is whether the Fourier series of $f$
> converges to $f$, or, more generally, whether $f$ is determined by its Fourier series.
> That is to say, if we know the Fourier coefficients of a function, can we find
> the function, and if so, how?
> This was on page 186 and then on page 187
> ~

If $\phi_n(x)$ is orthonormal on $[a, b]$ and if

$c_n =\int_a^b f(t) \overline{\phi_n(x)}dt $

we call $c_n$ the $n$th Fourier coefficient off relative to $\phi_n(x)$. We write

$f(x)\color{red}{\sim} \sum c_n  \phi_n(x)$

and call this series the Fourier series off (relative to $\phi_n(x)$ ).
Note that the symbol $\sim$ implies nothing about the convergence of the series;

Then  in theorem 8.11 rudin wrote this

Let {$\phi_n$} be orthonormal on $[a,b]$. Let $s_n(x) = \sum_{m=1}^n c_m\phi_m(x)$ be the nth partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$,
and suppose $t_n(x) = \sum_{m=1}^n y_m\phi_m(x)$.

> $$\int f \overline{t_n} =\int f \sum \overline{ y_m\phi_m(x)} \color{red}{=} \sum c_m  \overline{y_m} $$

but this is only possible when  $f(x)\color{red}{=} \sum c_n  \phi(x)$, so If this is the case how the symbol $\sim$ implies nothing about the convergence of the series? and How could this relation be an equality ?

Comment: Interchange the sum and the integral, then the integral of $f\bar{\phi_m}$ gives the result.

Comment: The sum for $s_n$ in finite so it makes sense without any convergence requirements.

Comment: @SungjinKim But how ? Should we prove that that series converge uniformly to $f$?

Comment: @Salciocould you elaborate more ? I mean it is $f$ that is multiplied with $\overline{t_n}$ and not $s_n$